# Get fail message from a function on powershell script

Tags: powershell, office365

I am not quite sure how to explain my problem, but I have a function that installs Office, imagine the person that runs this script does not have internet connection or does not have enough space on her hard drive. I have the XML file set to hide the setup interface so the user can't see the installation process. Just to be clear all my code works fine, just want add this feature so that if something goes wrong while the user runs the script I know where the error was.

This is my function:

```
Function Install-Office365OfficeProducts{
    Write-Host ""
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    Write-Host "Installing Office 365 ProPlus..."
    # Installing Office 365 ProPlus
    Install-Office365Product -path "$PSScriptRoot\setup.exe" -xmlPath "$PSScriptRoot\InstallO365.xml"
```

This is what I have tried:

```
if (Install-Office365OfficeProducts -eq 0) {
Write-Host "FAILED"}
```

I am very confused, I thought that a function that runs with no error returns 1 and when it runs with errors returns 0.

Also have tried to put the code like this:

```
try {
    Install-Office365Product -path "$PSScriptRoot\setup.exe" -xmlPath "$PSScriptRoot\InstallO365.xml"
} catch {
    Write-Host "Failed!"
}
```

EDIT:

Basically i want to be shown an error if the Office setup is not finished...

@Thomas

```
Function Install-Office365Product{
    Param (
        [string]$path,
        [string]$xmlPath
    )

    $arguments = "/configure `"$xmlPath`""
    try{
        Start-Process -FilePath "$path" -ArgumentList "$arguments" -Wait -NoNewWindow -ErrorAction Stop
    }catch{
        Write-Host "It was not possible to install the product!"
    }
}
```

Comment: You could check to see if it installed...
`Get-WmiObject win32_product | where{$_.Name -like "Microsoft Office*"} | select Name,Version`

Comment: Why don't you debug and see what the return value is in either case? Then you can change your code according to that.

Comment: I have tried that @PalleDue, the outcome when it finish the setup or not is always the same... For now i will use RileyCarney idea. Thanks for the options guys!

Comment: Where does this cmdlet come from: `Install-Office365Product`? Are you allowed to change it? If not, is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @Thomas, i added the code to the post, it is another function. I have the $path and $xmlPath declared in other place

Answer (score 0):

Your `try`/`catch`-block inside `Install-Office365OfficeProducts` is useless, because `Install-Office365Product` will not throw anything, except you pass wrong arguments. The `try`/`catch`-block inside `Install-Office365Product` will most likely also not catch anything. But you can of course evaluate the return code of your installer called with `Start-Process`:

```bsh
function Install-Office365Product {
    Param (
        [string]$path,
        [string]$xmlPath
    )

    $arguments = "/configure `"$xmlPath`""
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath "$path" -ArgumentList "$arguments" -Wait -PassThru -NoNewWindow
    if ($process.ExitCode -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "Installation successful"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Installation failed"
    }
}
```

Instead of writing to `stdout`, you can of course also throw an exception and handle it later in a higher function.